# Ubuntu low graphics mode

Tags: graphics

After one of the last updates, when I turn on my eeePC with Ubuntu 12.04, I see an error message saying that the system is in low graphics mode, and the offers me a series of options, but whatever I choose the prompt simply closes and nothing more happens.

How could I go fixing this problem if I am currently unable to reach the desktop? Is there some command line tool that can help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found out the problem was my disk which was 100% full, and this caused the error.

Simply running some cleanup procedure freed enough space to let the system reboot normally.